# Не устанавливается mongoDB на хостинг, требует yum

Tags: linux, mongodb, redhat, rhel, yum

Нужно установить на хостинг mongoDB, для это нужен yum,
в интеренете пишут что нужно устанавливать через rpm, но его тоже нету

```
Linux version 3.10.0-962.3.2.lve1.5.24.10.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@buildfarm03.cloudlinux.com) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat
4.8.5-36) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Mar 20 07:36:02 EDT 2019
```

Comment: приложите к тексту вопроса (нажав [edit]), вывод команды `$ cat /etc/*release*`

Comment: что такое *release*?

Comment: А каким мануалом ты пользуешься, чтобы воткнуть монгу?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/

Comment: Ну и в чём проблема? Там всё чётко и ясно - подрубаешь репу, ставишь из репы.

Comment: bash: yum: command not found, у меня на компе все норм поставилось без проблем на ubuntu, а в случае с хостингом всплывает много проблем,например yum и rpm  нету, а как без них установить не знаю, уже столько облазил страниц в интернете и ничего не помогает

Comment: Ну а в техподдержку хостера написать вопрос "где мой yum?" - не? Тут же явно проблема не общая.

Answer (score 0):

Как это "его тоже нету"?

Ну, для начала сделайте:

```
which yum
```

Если не окажется, то сделайте:

```
which rpm
```

Это уж точно окажется в системе, а значит вы сможете установить требуемый пакет с помощью `rpm`, заглянув [сюда](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-enterprise-on-red-hat/), а потом [сюда](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/s1-rpm-using). (Ну,  или наоборот! Как вам будет удобнее)

Update:

> например yum и rpm нету

Ну, это конечно странно, что их у вас нет. В таком случае, попробуйте:

```
which dnf
```

Наверняка, может оказаться так, что у вас стоит `dnf` и можно будет использовать `dnf`. Ну, а если и `dnf` отсуствует, то я не знаю, с чем это связано, и как это решить.

Comment: проверил все через which, никакой реакции, просто ничего не выводится